# Are there any known bioluminescent species of fungi found in the Pacific Northwest?

Tags: mycology, bioluminescence

This might not be the best place to ask this but since mycology is included I though I'd try: Some 21 years ago in late May of 2003 I was walking with a group of friends in the woods near Olympia, Washington sometime after 9PM when I noticed a blotch on the trunk of a tree(the tree was standing) glowing blue-green. It's glow was much dimmer than a firefly but it was clearly visible. We had no flashlights or lighters and it was pretty dark so I couldn't see what it actually looked like during daylight. It appeared to be either a slime mold or a crust fungus but I didn't touch it so I have no idea what its texture was. I talked to someone who also saw something very similar in the woods near Astoria, Oregon. So are there any known slime mold or crust fungus species that are bioluminescent? Nobody seems to have any idea what is could be and it makes me wonder if it is some species that has yet to be officially calatoged by science.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/mycology/comments/5o1mry/do_any_bioluminescent_mushrooms_grow_in_washington/

Comment: @BenBolker it clearly wasn't any of those. I would say it was not a mushroom in any sense of the word but more like a mold of sorts if you will. If I ever see it again, I will take a sample of it to a mycology lab.